# How can I convert a PNG file to JPEG file in php without creating a new file?

Tags: php

I know we can use `imagecreatefrompng` and `imagejpeg` functions to convert PNG to JPEG. But it creates a new file.

I just need file_get_contents() to store the file into database. That means I need JPEG file contents from my PNG file

eg:-

```
imagejpeg(imagecreatefrompng($_REQUEST['sig_data']), "test.jpeg");
$appSig = addslashes(file_get_contents("test.jpeg"));
```

Above example I need to create a 'test.jpeg' file. If I didn't pass that as an argument to `imagejpeg` function, it print the file in screen. And I can't do object buffering also. `imagejpg` function just return the status.

Comment: "to store the file into database" --- please **DON'T DO THAT**

Comment: @zerkms, I am working on a lagacy product. They can't afford changing the flow right now :). But that was not my question ... I know it is bad idea to store file content in server..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admittedly somewhat hacky, but you can capture the direct output of `imagejpeg`:

```
ob_start();
imagejpeg($resource);  // no file name
$imageData = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: I need content of the file. Above function do nothing . imagejpeg function just return the status.

Comment: If you copy and paste the above code as is, yes, it probably won't do anything. If you understand what it does and adapt it to your situation, it works.

Comment: @deceze: how dare you to ask OP to start thinking?!

Comment: @zerkms So sorry, I'll get on the bus and drive over to the OP to hold his hands right away.

Comment: @deceze file_get_content($imageData) return nothing. Can you explain me how to go further

Comment: *facepalm* @Sahal Why `file_get_contents($imageData)`? `$imageData` ***is*** the image data. Do no more. Insert `$imageData` into the database.

Comment: Thanks to all, it worked. Actually I was not doing `addslashes`. Thats is the reason it was not inserting. Thought some error in file contents

Comment: @deceze Issue resolved, otherwise I would called you my home. By bus or train some how I would offer you something :)

Comment: @Sahal Well, you'd probably have to pay for a flight ticket, I'd guess you're a bit far away for public transport... ;)

Comment: @deceze Anyway Thanks. I have gone-through you profile and really Impressed. Can you suggest me something in PHP what to learn and what is the future of PHP. As it is not related to this post, I don't have any other media to ask you :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21262/discussion-between-sahal-and-deceze)

Comment: @Sahal Learn to think things through, read the documentation and understand what every little piece does in detail. It's the only way to get better.